# tomcat servlet HttpServletRequest.getCookies() error

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, cookies, jmeter

It's wired, but is true.
I use jmeter send http request which includes a Cookie which is like `data=5ExJK/9ZyDsbiA8cuUXCBQ==`. I can see the value on View Results Tree.

But when on tomcat servlet,

```
    Cookie[] cookies = req.getCookies();  

    String[] cooks = null;   
    String username = "";   

    if (cookies != null) {   
        for (Cookie coo : cookies) {   
            if(coo.getName().equals("data")){
               String encrypt = coo.getValue();

    .....
```

variable `encrypt` becomes `5ExJK/9ZyDsbiA8cuUXCBQ`. double `=` disappear.
When use fiddle as proxy to see the Cookie, I can see the double `=`  with my eyes.

when use browser, variable `encrypt` becomes  to have double `=`.

what has happen  in tomcat servlet? how to fix it?

jmeter  3.0 r1743807,
tomcat 8.0.28

Comment: The equals sign has special meaning - use encodeURIComponent on the JavaScript side and URLDecoder.decode() on the Java side.  Don't just put the Base64 encoding in the cookie.

Comment: Quite right. I use Base64 encoding in cookie.i change to others. All work as  expect.